# How to place ranking like top 10 and put x axis labels on right of horizontal bar chart?

Tags: highcharts

## Current Chart

[image: highcharts - put x axis labels on right of horizontal bar chart]

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    labels: {
        x : 25,
        align: 'left'
    }
},
```

My Script in here
http://jsfiddle.net/puff0211/dtcLn8sm/14/

## Desired Chart

[image: highcharts - place ranking like top 10]

Does anyone know to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Comment: thanks image syntax, I cannot use yet. @ThomasRollet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solutions here is to slightly change the position of both axes via `left` property (it's not documented but it works) and create additional labels using **SVG Renderer**. `chart.events.load` is a good place for it because when it launches ticks values and positions are already computed - we can use them to create additional labels:

```
    load: function() {
      var ticks = this.xAxis[0].ticks,
        renderer = this.renderer;

      for (var prop in ticks) {
        var t = ticks[prop];
        if (t.label) {
          var coords = t.label.xy,
            label = renderer.text(t.pos + 1, coords.x - additionLabelsOffset, coords.y).add();
        }
      }
    }
(...)

xAxis: {
   left: axesOffset
   (...)
}, 
yAxis: {
   left: axesOffset
   (...)
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/cq2otgr1/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text

Comment: I think your solution is better than me, because I try to export png, my solution will put on wrong position.

Answer (score 0):

### My solution is simple.

1. Let chart margin keep width with left lable.(api use `chart.margin`)
2. Allow X Axis can display 2 lable. (api use `useHTML` and `formatter` )

Code:

```
    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        margin: [ 0, 0, 70, 70]
    },
    {...},
    xAxis: {
        labels: {
            x : 0,
            align: 'left',
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function() {
                return '<div style="position: relative; top: 0px; right: 50px"> No. '+ (this.pos + 1) +'</div>\
                <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 20px"><b>'+ this.value +'</div>';
        }
    }
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/puff0211/pv84nLub/

API Reference:

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.margin
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.useHTML
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter